# Parse, how to send push notification to targeted users

Tags: push-notification, installation, parse-platform

I have successfully setup parse push notifications and in my installation table I have both an installation, and device token. What I'm really trying to do is send a push notification to certain users, rather than certain devices. How do I bing the installations table to the uses table, so that I can make a query by users and get back a deviceid to push to

Answer (score 1):

From https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS, section "Using Advanced Targeting".

> You can even create relationships between your Installation objects
>   and other classes saved on Parse. To associate a PFInstallation with a
>   particular user, for example, you can simply store the current user on
>   the PFInstallation.

```
// Associate the device with a user
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

Now you can create a query on the installation table, where "user" is the user you want to send a push notification to.

Finally, use that query when constructing the push object.

Example in Objective-C (adjust accordingly, if you're sending the push in some other language):

```
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:someUser]; // where some user is the user object that is to receive a push notification

PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery];
[push setMessage:@"Hi there!"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Comment: I actually got that far after I asked that question (although I'm just using a username field rather than the user object). I'm still getting strange results though, in the data browser, it still says sent to 0 recipients regardless of what the query is (even if I pass no query to send to all recipients).